# my macbook pro will not let me have ubuntu...please help!

Tags: boot, usb, mac, macbook, livedvd

I have acquired a 2009 macbook pro 15 at a great price, but I can't seem to figure it out in order to get ubuntu as my only os.

I first placed my boot disc I have always used and it would not run. Then I heard about the need for third party download needs and went to unetbootin and downloaded it both on my mac and another pc. (each of the following attempts are doubled because I have used both computers to create the live boot utilities)
I have tried a new live dvd of 14.04, and a different usb, then I reformatted the first usb and loaded it with ubuntu 14.04...and then I reformatted the usb to the mac recommended loaded it once more with 14.04. all of these would not even show up as a boot option when restarting and holding the alt/option key. (also I have checked to see my hard drive is not encrypted and it showed that it was not.)

Can I just simply wipe the whole thing and start fresh with ubuntu like I did with my other pc's or is that not possible with apple? please help I really want my ubuntu back!

Comment: Are you still trying to get Ubuntu to work? Did you try using a DVD?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick) is the ubuntu's official document to prepare install Ubuntu on Mac. You have to install a different hybrid **bootloader called  "rEFIt"** which is a boot menu and maintenance toolkit for EFI-based machines like the Intel Macs. You can use it to boot multiple operating systems easily, including triple-boot setups with Boot Camp. It also provides an easy way to enter and explore the EFI pre-boot environment.

Just be careful while you wipe the Mac HDD to not to use the all space. I had my old mac mini (early 2006) which does not support the internet recovery and I made it working with Ubuntu however now it's almost a brick, since it doesn't boot into ubuntu (after latest update) and doesn't recognize the latest installation media. Last option will be to replace the HDD and do a fresh install.

Alternatively, you can use virtual box or VMWare Fusion to run Ubuntu. It runs like a tiger without any problem.

Good Luck.

Comment: Finally got rEFIt to work after a week of tinkering...and tried to boot from live disc. I am really getting discouraged! even checked for best ubuntu to fit my mac (which happened to be 12.04 and still will not let me have ubuntu! what is going on? I have never had this much trouble. I have been trying everything that I have been told so far in this thread and others but still can't get it to work.